# Why do I get null value of LiveData after I have used async{} in Android Studio with Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-room

The Code A query `LiveData<List<MVoice>>` with Room and display them in `RecyclerView` control, it works well.

I know that query LiveData with Room will be run in a background thread, so `val dd` will return null in Code B.

I think `val bb` will return correct `List<MVoice>` in Code C, but in fact, it return null, why ?

**Code A**

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener {        
  mHomeViewModel.listVoice().observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ listMVoice->
    adapter.submitList(listMVoice)
  }        
}


@Dao
interface DBVoiceDao{ 
   @Query("SELECT * FROM voice_table ORDER BY createdDate desc")
   fun listVoice():LiveData<List<MVoice>>
}


class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao){
    fun listVoice()= mDBVoiceDao.listVoice()
}


class HomeViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : ViewModel() {
    fun listVoice()= mDBVoiceRepository.listVoice()
}
```

**Code B**

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener { 
   val dd=mHomeViewModel.listVoice().value   //It return null   
}

... //It's the same as Code A
```

**Code C**

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener {         
   lifecycleScope.launch{
      val aa=async { mHomeViewModel.listVoice() }
      val bb=aa.await().value       //It return null too    
   }
}

... //It's the same as Code A
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code can actually be simplified by removing `async-await` and it will work the same.

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
    val aa = mHomeViewModel.listVoice().value // It will be null too.
}
```

The code inside `async { ... }` is not how you probably think it works. To explain this;

- `LiveData.getValue()` is not a **suspending function**. Hence, the `async { ... }` returns immediately.
- `LiveData.getValue()` is intended to get its current value without waiting for next first value. This is the reason why it's not a suspending function.

Comment: Thanks!  but you know that `val dd` will return null in Code B and it's without `async-await`.

Comment: @HelloCW Yeah, it's the exact same thing like in Code B.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that `mHomeViewModel.listVoice().value` always return null except invoken in  `observe()` ?

Comment: @HelloCW You're welcome. Practically, not always. But in your case, it is. You can replace the `DBVoiceDao.listVoice()` with `suspending function` instead of returning the LiveData.